# What international sport do not have age limits for championship competitions?

Tags: rules, trivia, history, international-sports, swimming

I view that [Alzain Tareq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alzain_Tareq) took part in the [Kazan 2015](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2015/aug/07/alzain-tarez-10-year-old-swimmer-youngest-ever-world-championships) swim championship at age of 10!

It seems that FINA (International Swimming Federation) has no age limits for races. Are there any other international sport where a "baby" can take part at the event?

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, Football is one of these. The only restriction is a maximum age of 23 for the men's competition.

> **Men’s Tournament**
>
> 4. All players participating in the preliminary and final competitions of the  Tournament shall be **born on or after 1 January 1993**.
>      However, a maximum  of three male players who do not meet this age
>      limit may also be included in  the official list of players for the
>      final competition.
>
> **Women’s Tournament**
>
> 5. There are **no age restrictions** for the players participating in the Women’s  Tournament.

» [FIFA Rules for Rio 2016](http://resources.fifa.com/mm/document/tournament/competition/02/54/40/46/oftsregulationsrio2016-e_neutral.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

[Bowls](https://www.bowlsengland.com/about-us/rules-and-regulations) has no minimum or maximum age restriction on most competitions.

However, most national and international competitions require entrants to be affiliated to a recognised club and most clubs have a minimum age limit of 9 or 10.

There are some competitions with a minimum age, but these are the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Wales have named 11-year-old Anna Hursey in their squad for the table tennis event at the 2018 Commonwealth Games. She has already (at age 10) represented Wales at the European Championships.

[Source - BBC Sport](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/wales/42788772)